# Can you help me write htaccess that directs others to static html and me to my Codeigniter site?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Here's the problem, I'm doing a rewrite of a Codeigniter site that has the requisite htaccess for removing the index.php.

While doing the rewrite, I want to redirect visitors to a static HTML page while I do the rewrite and test. In other words, I want to access the Codeigniter site as normal but not show it to others yet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You will need to have a look here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess5.shtml you basically have to deny all but your own public ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. It basically says: anything coming from an IP other than the one specified, load index.html.

Therefore when you load the page, you will see the rewrite take effect as it should, while everybody else will just see the index.html.

Make sure you use your public facing IP in the rule below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1\.1\.1\.1  #your ip goes here, escape the dots!
    RewriteRule .* index.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I do have a suggestion though. Try and setup a local development environment. You can change things as much as you want without afffecting your users...

Comment: Thanks, seems to be basic enough for me to grasp!

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-for-webmasters.html

Comment: Appreciate the heads up, fantastic resource but the answer by jfoucher may be more basic for my understanding. But the resource you provided, most helpful if/when I learn more on htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do the same. I came to the conclusion that using a .htaccess file is very annoying especially if you have a dynamic IP. Basically what I've been doing is using an auth library I've been writing to restrict access to functions I don't want people to see and then check their role ID and redirect them to a static site.

So my role ID is 5 and a guest is 0. So all visitors would be 0 and so you could go restrict(array('5'), 'http://www.mysite.com/static.html') in your controller and perhaps use a redirect.

My library might be of use to you: https://github.com/Vheissu/WolfAuth-for-Codeigniter-2.0-  there are of course many ways of doing things like this. This is how I've combated it. Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Dwayne, saw your Auth lib some days ago, looks quite promising. I've been meaning to take it for a test drive but time doing this re-write is killing me! Thanks again for both the answer and the lib...if I use it, will provide feedback.